# Откуда берётся "прямо сейчас"?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Относительное время для различных событий на сайте содержит фразу *"прямо сейчас"*. Например:

> [image: прямо сейчас]

Данный текст автоматически обновляется без необходимости ручной подгрузки страницы. И уже через несколько секунд становится, например, таким:

> [image: 51 сек. назад]

И если *"сек. назад"* я ещё могу найти в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261799?qt=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA.%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4), то *"прямо сейчас"* [там нет](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264764?qt=%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81).

Откуда оно берётся?